# ANOVA: testing homogeneity of variance via D’Agostino- Pearson test?

Tags: anova, f-statistic, skew-normal-distribution

I would be grateful for a cross-check on my understanding of the criteria for valid ANOVA analysis. The orthodoxy I've always used is the Hartley’s Fmax test, if that fails ANOVA is simply no-go.

The question is in two parts:

- Could D’Agostino-Pearson test for normality alone be used to justify ANOVA analysis? If this is a concern that what safe guards would be requested that the homogeneity of variance is sufficient for valid ANOVA analysis?
- Secondly, I never considered D’Agostino-Pearson test as a compelling basis to perform parametrics *per se*, so in particular I'd look at a Q-Q test. Is that view correct?

Comment: You'll see this discussed repeatedly and in depth on this site. In general using hypothesis tests for normality or homogeneity of variance, as criterion to deciding whether anova is appropriate, is not a good idea. See perhaps [towardsdatascience.com/stop-testing-for-normality-dba96bb73f90](https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-testing-for-normality-dba96bb73f90). So, yes, you are much better off examining the q-q plot of residuals and the plot of residuals vs. predicted values.

Comment: @SalMangiafico This is very useful, thank you. Could you kindly put this as an answer please and I can mark it as accepted? This is pretty close to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll see this discussed repeated and in depth on this site.

In general using hypothesis tests for normality or homogeneity of variance, as criterion to deciding whether anova is appropriate, is not a good idea.  See perhaps [towardsdatascience.com/stop-testing-for-normality-dba96bb73f90](https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-testing-for-normality-dba96bb73f90).

So, yes, you are much better off examining the q-q plot of residuals and the plot of residuals vs. predicted values.